# Facebook PHP Business SDK Test Event

Tags: php, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-conversions-api

I am trying to set up the PHP Business SDK from Facebook on my site. I want to run a test event, but am unsure how to go about this. This is what I have:

```
$user_data = (new UserData())
    ->setEmails(array('joe@eg.com'))
    ->setPhones(array('12345678901', '14251234567'))
    // It is recommended to send Client IP and User Agent for Conversions API Events.
    ->setClientIpAddress($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'])
    ->setClientUserAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
    ->setFbc('fb.1.1554763741205.AbCdEfGhIjKlMnOpQrStUvWxYz1234567890')
    ->setFbp('fb.1.1558571054389.1098115397');
        
$content = (new Content())
    ->setProductId('product123')
    ->setQuantity(1)
    ->setDeliveryCategory(DeliveryCategory::HOME_DELIVERY);
        
$custom_data = (new CustomData())
    ->setContents(array($content))
    ->setCurrency('usd')
    ->setValue(123.45);
        
$event = (new Event())
    ->setEventName('Purchase')
    ->setEventTime(time())
    ->setEventSourceUrl('http://jaspers-market.com/product/123')
    ->setUserData($user_data)
    ->setCustomData($custom_data)
    ->setActionSource(ActionSource::WEBSITE);
        
$events = array();
array_push($events, $event);
        
$request = (new EventRequest($pixel_id))
    ->setEvents($events);
$response = $request->execute();
print_r($response);
```

It looks like I can use `test_event_code` somewhere to send a test event, but I am not sure where to set this in the above code.

Any help would be great

Comment: Did you get this figured out? I want to do the same thing.

Answer (score 5):

This is possible by adding the following in your request: *->setTestEventCode('TEST12345')*

So the last part of your code will look like this:

```
$request = (new EventRequest($pixel_id))
    ->setTestEventCode('TEST12345')
    ->setEvents($events);

$response = $request->execute();
print_r($response);
```

Replace **TEST12345** with your own test code. Hope this is helpful.